# Pandas.to_csv thousand separator

Tags: pandas

Pandas version: 0.19.2

I have a dataframe which contains columns with numbers up to 10,000,000.00. I would like to export the numbers in a format which has no decimal places but does have commas as thousand separators. In the `pandas.to_csv()` function, how should I specify the `float_format` parameter. I have tried various combinations but seem to get any to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that pd.to_csv is using the old limited [% format](https://pyformat.info/) , a shortcut would be converting the dataframe before writing to csv. Something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[112223344,123456.55,999999],'b':[4,52323242352.2,6],'c':[7,8,9]})

df['a']=df.a.apply(lambda x : '{0:,}'.format(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it does not achieve what I want. The `decimal` parameter changes 4123.00 to 4.123,00 ie the european number style. Whereas, I want 4123 to be formatted like 4,123.